# ASP Net Gridview error Two components with the same id can't be added to the application

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview that is built by unioning several tables.  Each table has a primary key called Pkey.  My Problem is that the gridview errors out when it runs into the same Pkey number when displaying the data.

```
Here is the query
SELECT Pkey, Status, EffectiveDate, 'Budget Element' as RequestType, DescribeRequest
FROM tblBudgetElement
union
SELECT Pkey, Status, EffectiveDate, 'Expense Element' as RequestType, DescribeRequest
FROM tblExpenseElement
union
SELECT Pkey, Status, EffectiveDate, 'Expense Hl' as RequestType, DescribeRequest
FROM tblExpenseHLevel
```

I have tried using a simple bound field.  And tried creating a hyperlink field in the code behind.

Here is the gridview

```
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Pkey" HeaderText="Pkey">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestType" HeaderText="Request Type">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="EffectiveDate" HeaderText="Effective Date"  DataFormatString = "{0:d}" >
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="DescribeRequest" HeaderText="Describe Request">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Top" BorderWidth="0"/>
                    <ItemStyle BorderWidth="0"/>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/MagnifyingClass.gif" />

                        <cc1:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server" 
                           PopupControlID="Panel1" 
                           TargetControlID="Image1" 
                           DynamicContextKey='<%# Eval("Pkey") %>' 
                           DynamicControlID="Panel1" 
                           DynamicServiceMethod="GetRequest" Position="right"> 
                        </cc1:PopupControlExtender> 
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>                
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Silver" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Show your aspx file (The Web part of your GridView)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in the GridView definition, but in your SQL query. Without knowing the database structure, it looks like each table will have its own values for PKey, so of course you're going to encounter duplicate values. And I'll bet (though you didn't show that part of your GridView code) you have "PKey" defined as the DataKeyValue for the GridView.

Again without knowing the database structure, I'm guessing the query could be written differently (or the database slightly modified) to retrieve the rows you need, with a unique key for each one.